# '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<dynamic>' flutter

Tags: arrays, json, flutter, dart, http-get

I just started out consuming `api` with `dart` and `flutter`. I completed several ones successfully but i find this one a little tricky. So, I am working on showing a list of items for users to select from. The text on each list item should be the data key. Once it is tapped on, it shows all the details for that index.

This is the response am trying to consume.

**Response**

```
{
    "status": "success",
    "data": {
        "Ikeja Electric (IKEDC)": {
            "service_id": "ikeja-electric",
            "type": [
                "prepaid",
                "postpaid"
            ]
        },
        "Eko Electric (EKEDC)": {
            "service_id": "eko-electric",
            "type": [
                "prepaid",
                "postpaid"
            ]
        },
        "Ibadan Electric (IBEDC)": {
            "service_id": "ibadan-electric",
            "type": [
                "prepaid",
                "postpaid"
            ]
        },
        "Kano Electric (KEDCO)": {
            "service_id": "kano-electric",
            "type": [
                "prepaid",
                "postpaid"
            ]
        },
        "Jos Electricity Distribution (JED)": {
            "service_id": "jos-electric",
            "type": [
                "prepaid",
                "postpaid"
            ]
        },
        "Port-Harcourt Electric (PHED)": {
            "service_id": "portharcourt-electric",
            "type": [
                "prepaid",
                "postpaid"
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

**get Request**

```
Map<String, dynamic> networks;
...

fetchNetworks() async{
    var uri = ApiService.BASE_URL + "endpoint";
    try {
      final response = await http.get(
        uri,
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json','Authorization': 'Bearer ' + _bloc.bearerToken, },
      );
      final responseJson = json.decode(response.body);
      print(responseJson.toString());
      setState(() {
        widget.networks = responseJson["data"];
      });
      return responseJson;
    } catch (exception) {
      print(exception);
    }
  }
}

I
```

f am to use a model, how do i structure it accordingly?

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest to use this library https://github.com/k-paxian/dart-json-mapper
It will allow you to nicely map your complicated JSON to Dart Classes